# securing credentials on front end react-native

Tags: react-native, security, frontend, api-key

I am creating an app using react-native. This app requires some sensitive data which must be stored securely and there are various options for that e.g, [expo-secure-store](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/).

Now i am a but confused regarding securing the data on front end.

I am using react-native-async-storage to store other data on front end.

Now it is treated as a bad practice to use the same for sensitive data.

But my question is, say i use expo-secure-store for sensitive data, but at the time of saving it like this;

```
SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);
```

where value is the sensitive part, isn't that still getting exposed while setting it in the code.

Please explain this and describe some better practices to store (or access) sensitive data on front end.

Thanks!

Comment: What should it be secure against? What is the threat?

Comment: @GaborLengyel tbh i don't know about all the threats, but just heard about some. Like by reverse engineering (i may be wrong), one can extract the code of an app, means one can access all the creds in the code (say api keys etc). Also, it is not recommended to store sensitive data even in async storage (which clearly means there are threats).

Comment: You cannot prevent the user of this app controlling the execution environment (ie. the device where your client is running) from knowing _everything_ in your app. Your app bundle should not have secrets built into it, nor should it download data that you don't want the actual user to have access to.

Comment: @GaborLengyel but what if we needed some creds there, like api keys etc. How to get them securely there

Comment: For example you could have a backend (server-side) where you can securely store such credentials, and you can then authenticate your users and implement access control to allow usage of such credentials (without exposing the actual secrets). Or in a different model, you could have your users seamlessly create such credentials for themselves (so it's ok for users to have them), if your usecase allows for that.

Comment: @GaborLengyel but i cannot do so here. there is no way to do so here. I must get the key  on front end

Comment: The legitimate user of the app will always have a way to extract those. Think of it like this: the user _is_ the device, the suer _is_ the app. If the app can access it, so can the user of that app, if they fully control the device. Secure storages are secure against _others_ (this is why I asked what it should be secure against), and not the legit user. These are storages _of that user_.

Comment: @GaborLengyel Thanks for your time. But i already know it, as i said, how to secure the things. Because there are cases where we need creds on frontend like auth tokens, api keys (as in case of google maps) etc.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the Google Maps Android SDK has instructions for restricting the API key usage to an app fingerprint: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key

This reduces the risk of including the key in your app by only allowing the key to be used from a source that matches the fingerprint of the app certificate.

In practice the value of a Google Maps API key is fairly low, and is not the most attractive target for a bad actor. Frontend API keys are sensitive in that you can be billed for their usage, but unless you are specifically targeted, it's not a likely attack vector.

Truly sensitive keys, like those used to generate auth credentials or payment data, should always be kept on the backend, and any decent third-party service will be set up in a way that forces this to be the case (for example, Stripe).

You may get better answers by asking how or when to store specific keys.

Comment: I know about the api key restrictions. But again, what if we have to use some sensitive creds on front end. How to do so.